# Under these assumptions, is a function convex?

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

I have a function $f(x,y) \in \mathcal{C^{2}}$, $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial{x}} < 0$ and $\frac{\partial^2  f(x,y)}{\partial^2 {x}} > 0$. Same hypothesis for $y$. So $f_y(x)$ is monotone and convex for every $x$. Same conclusion for $y$. No information about mixed partial derivates.

Is $f(x,y)$ a convex function?

The study of Hessian matrix doesn't give me any results, and I don't find any counterexample. Sorry for my English.

EDIT: Possible solution. $f_{y_{0}}(x)=f(x,y_0)$, where $y_0$ is fixed, is monote and convex, for every fixed $y_0$. So the set $epi f_{y_{0}}(x) =\{ (x,t) | t >= f_{y_{0}}(x) \}$ is convex. The set  $\bigcup_{y_{0}}  \{ epi f_{y_{0}}(x)\} $ is $epi f(x,y)$. Generally union of convex sets isn't convex, but in this case yes, because $f(x,y) \in \mathcal{C^{2}}$ so the union is "without holes". Ok, I know that it isn't written in a formal way, but is the idea right?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. Take for example the function

$$f(x,y) = x^2+ y^2 + 100 xy$$

Then the Hessian is $$[2, 100; 100, 2]$$ which is not positive semi-definite since its determinant $4 - 100^2 < 0$.

Another example:

$$f(x,y) = e^{-x} + e^{-y} + 100e^{-xy}$$

Again the Hessian is $$[e^{-x}, 100xy e^{-xy}; 100xye^{-xy}, e^{-y}]$$ The determinant is $$e^{-x-y} - (100xy)^2 e^{-2xy}$$ which will be negative for some values of $x,y$. So the function cannot be convex.

Comment: Wrong example. The partial derivate $\frac {\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ isn't negative for every $x$.

Comment: The same conceptualization holds. See added example.

Comment: First example: $\frac {\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ = $2x + 100y$ and it is positive for $(1,0)$ so the condition $\frac {\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} < 0$ is invalid. Same answer for the second example: $\frac {\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ = $-e^{-x} - 100y e^{-xy}$ and it is positive for $(0,-1)$, so condition is invalid.